Make a shortcut to a Windows 11 "App" (not Program)
I'm trying to find the address or link or something to refer to a Windows App.
Every search result gives instructions that say "app" but mean "program", which is not useful.
Right clicking the app only gives options to view the limited windows settings it directly configured.
This solution doesn't seem to work in Windows 11

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@FrankThomas, Windows new "apps" are stored in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps, on this Win10 PC... but that is useless, since one cannot open a new app directly. E.G, Camera is at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_2020.902.20.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsCamera.exe, but that executable will not run from the Command Line, nor by creating a link to it, nor by double-clicking in Explorer.

This workaround from Thurrott works in Windows 10 -- please let me know if it no longer works in Windows 11:

Press WindowsR simultaneously.
Type shell:AppsFolder. and press Enter.
Right-click an item and select Create shortcut.
Create it on the Desktop.

It's surprising that Microsoft, in Windows 11, would have removed the ability to drag-and-drop an item from the Start Menu to the Desktop to create a shortcut -- is there some third-party application, or perhaps damage to the OS, preventing this? Is it a corporate PC that has a Group Policy interfering?

seems to work for me in w11
